# Using RxAndroid ,after receiving data from network where (in which method ) I should call the data insertion part in DB?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I receive data from network ,I implemented that part, but after receiving data from server in other thread, I want to save the data in Data base,which I want to implement not in main  thread,so after receiving data where I should call the DB insertion method.Here is my code

```
Observable<List<PhotoAlbum>> searchResponseObservable =
            mService.getAPI().getAlbums().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    searchResponseObservable.subscribe(new Observer<List<PhotoAlbum>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.i("test","onComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i("test","onComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<PhotoAlbum> photoAlbums) {
            view().showSearchResult(photoAlbums);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `doOnNext()` to insert received data into your DB like this:

```
Observable<List<PhotoAlbum>> searchResponseObservable = mService.getAPI()
                        .getAlbums()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .doOnNext(photoAlbums -> insertIntoDb(photoAlbums))
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        searchResponseObservable.subscribe(new Observer<List<PhotoAlbum>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.i("test","onComplete");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.i("test","onComplete");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<PhotoAlbum> photoAlbums) {
                view().showSearchResult(photoAlbums);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flatMap to save in database and use Schedulers IO (Schedulers.io()) for background process

```
  mService.getAPI().getAlbums().flatMap(new Func1<List<PhotoAlbum>, Observable<GetDriversResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<GetDriversResponse> call(GetDriversResponse mResponse) {
                    return mDatabaseHelper.setMyBus(mResponse);
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Action1<GetDriversResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(List<PhotoAlbum> photoAlbums{view().showSearchResult(photoAlbums);  }}, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Throwable throwable) {    
                            throwable.printTrack
                        }
                    }));
```